# Drop-down menu class in bootstrap-multiselect.js interfering with my custom dropdown-menu class

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

The following css from my custom.css file builds on the core boostrap css and has the class dropdown-menu. This class is in conflict with the dropdown-menu class in the davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect.js file which also uses the core bootstrap css dropdown-menu class.

Is there a way to make the custom.css dropdown-menu class more selective as not to affect the bootstrap-multiselect elements without using an id? I can't use id because I have multiple dropdown-menus on the same page.

The section of custom.css that inteferes:

```
.dropdown-menu {
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    border: 1px solid #D6D6D6;
    border-top-color: #EEEEEE;
    border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a {
    color: #515151;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #515151;
}
```

davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect - bootstrap-multiselect.js:

```
templates: {              
            button: '<button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"></button>',
                ul: '<ul class="multiselect-container dropdown-menu"></ul>',                
            filter: '<li class="multiselect-item filter"><div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></span><input class="form-control multiselect-search" type="text"></div></li>',                
                li: '<li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><label></label></a></li>',                
            divider: '<li class="multiselect-item divider"></li>',                
            liGroup: '<li class="multiselect-item group"><label class="multiselect-group"></label></li>'            
        }
```

dropdown menu html:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="../about-us.html">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="../blog.html">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="../blog-timeline.html">Blog Timeline</a></li>
</ul>
```

multiselect html:

```
<select class="multiselect" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
    <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
    <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
</select>
```

Comment: forgot to also paste your html...?

Answer (score 0):

Your bootstrap-multiselect.css doesnot show the .multiselect class given to select tag?

Comment: Okay. Well, when I delete the drop-down menu part of the custom.css file, the multiselect looks correct. Similarly if I delete the bootsrap-multiselect.css line that calls the css file as well, the select box does not look correct.

Comment: Can you try renaming all of .dropdown-menu to some other class name like .dropdown alone?

Comment: I tried that but it jacked up my dropdown menus. I guess the bootstrap.css needs them to be named dropdown menu. However, I just found the following code in the bootstrap-multiselect.js file that may be causing the conflict:  
            ul: '<ul class="multiselect-container dropdown-menu"></ul>',

Comment: Ok. Then probably we should be able to resolve with an id added to drop-down menu..which you do not want it though.

Comment: Adding the id did work but I have read that I shouldn't add the same id to multiple elements, is this correct?

Comment: Yes, we should not use same id multiple times in a page, but in we can use the id across different pages.

Comment: Okay, that's what I'll do. Thank you. I would give you up votes but I don't have the reputation to do so.

Comment: You are welcome. No worries about reputation, it should help you..that's all..cheers:)